# How am I supposed to defeat Iblis (Silver's Story)?

Tags: ps3, sonic-the-hedgehog-2006

This boss is extremely difficult.

I know how to catch the huge fireball, but when I counter-attack with the huge fireball and he does the waves of flames, he destroys the entire foothold.

When I looked on a video on YouTube, he lowers his head so you can use the powers on his head but for me, the entire platform gets destroyed. If I glide, the bar eventually runs out and I die. What can I do?

Also when I grab a lot of small fireballs and try to throw them, they instantly blow up sometimes.

Please note that my PS3 is European (UK) and the game is American. (I'm not sure if this is relevant but is listed just in case).